# ¿funcion para extraer terminos de expresiones aritmeticas con clase re (regular expression)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy planteando el siguiente problema:

Una función que toma un expresión aritmética en `string` y retorna un tipo numérico.
En forma conceptual esta es la lógica (no código):

```
evalExpresion("A+B/C-D") = evaluarExpresion("A") + evaluarExpresion("B/C-D")
evalExpresion("A") = A
evalExpresion("B/C-D") = evalExpresion("B/C") - evalExpresion("D")
evalExpresion("B/C") = evalExpresion("B") / evalExpresion("C")
evalExpresion("D") = D
evalExpresion("B") = B
evalExpresion("C") = C
```

Donde A, B, C y D (sin las comillas) representan números.

La consulta puntual es:
¿Qué función de la clase ***re*** permite obtener por separado los argumentos del operador en concreto?

En el caso de la cadena "A+B/C-D", para el primer operador "+", lo que busco es obtener por separado la subcadena "A" y "B/C-D" y de forma análoga para el resto.

Saludos.

Comment: sal_defrutas, es correcto que `A+B/C-D` se descomponga en `A` y `B/C-D`, en vez de `A`, `B/C`y `D`?

Comment: Lo ideal seria separar todos los terminos en un solo llamado, lo puse asi por que representaria una recursion al encontrar el primer operador "+". Luego se aplicaria lo mismo para el operador "-" separar "B/C-D" en el siguiente llamado.

Comment: Inicialmente, si sólo quieres separar los términos, te basta con **re.compile("\+|\-|\/").split("A+B/C-D")**. Con eso obtienes una lista con cada término. Sin embargo, pierdes los operadores. Supongo que después quieres realizar cada operación.

Comment: Gracias RodrigoN, me funciono. Respecto perder los operadores, plante la siguiente solucion:
sumas = re.split(r'\+','A+B/C-D') 
restas = [re.split(r'\-', x) for x in sumas] 
diviciones = [[re.split(r'\/', y) for y in x] for x in restas] 
productos = [[[re.split(r'\+', z) for z in y] for y in x] for x in diviciones]. Al final, la variable productos tiene tiene listas anidadas, en el caso del ejemplo es [[[['A']]], [[['B'], ['C']], [['D']]]]. Luego vastaria recorrer a la inversa con funciones reduce.